# How do I correctly upgrade angular 2 (npm) to the latest version?

Tags: npm, angular

Recently I started Angular 2 tutorial at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/.

and left off with Angular 2 beta 8.
Now I resumed the tutorial and latest beta is beta 14.

If I simply do **npm update** a few modules (preloaded with the tutorial) are updated but not Angular2 (I can see that with **npm ls**).

If I do **npm update angular 2** or **npm update angular2@2.0.0beta.14** it just does nothing either.

Comment: `npm install angular2@2.0.0beta.14 --save` should do it, I think.

Comment: yes, it worked. check out my comment to Cosmin's answer

Comment: For people coming to this from Google, be aware that there may be issues after updating Angular itself, that require you to also update angular-cli if you're using that. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli for the details on how.

Comment: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The command `npm update -D && npm update -S` will update all packages inside `package.json` to their latest version, **according to [their defined version range](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies)**. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update#recording-updates-with---save).

If you want to update Angular from a version prior to `2.0.0-rc.1`, then you'll need to manually edit `package.json`, as Angular was split into several npm modules. Without this, as [angular2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2) package points to `2.0.0-beta.21`, you'll never get to use the latest version of Angular.

A list with some of the most common modules that you'll need to get started can be found in the [quickstart repository](https://github.com/angular/quickstart).

**Notes:**

- **A cool way to stay up to date with your packages' latest version** is to use [`npm outdated`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated) which shows you all outdated packages together with their wanted and latest version.
- The reason why we need to chain two commands, `npm update -D` and `npm update -S` is to overcome [this bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10531) until it's fixed.

Comment: thanks Cosmin. I followed Joe Clay advice and it worked. Your is however a more general solution which is definitely good. I also recommend using **npm-install-missing** (another npm package) in case of any outdated dependencies.

Comment: That module is quite old and I think it's due to the fact that npm was having some problems with `npm update`, which got fixed in the meantime. A cool way to see if `npm update --save` worked is to see if `npm outdated` doesn't display anything.

Comment: npm install @angular not angular2 :-)

Comment: @Elisabeth I'm not sure what you mean. `@angular` doesn't exist. [angular2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2) is the correct npm name.

Comment: My npm name is @angular. angular2 was before the beta17 kind like that

Comment: @Elisabeth I've finally understood and I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: any update to this? is the 'bug' fixed. and isn't -S now optional?

Comment: If create using Angular CLI, just update angular cli using npm install --save-dev @angular-cli@latest and update project using ng update -next

Answer (score 54):

Another nice package which I used for migrating form a beta version of Angular2 to `Angular2 2.0.0 final` is `npm-check-updates`

It shows the latest available version of all packages specified within your package.json. In contrast to `npm outdated` it is also capable to edit your package.json, enabling you to do a `npm upgrade` later.

**Install**

`sudo npm install -g npm-check-updates`

**Usage**

`ncu`for display

`ncu -u` for re-writing your package.json

Comment: great works for me but what https://stackoverflow.com/a/46148361/2055782 will do ?

Answer (score 31):

**Upgrade to latest Angular 5**

Angular Dep packages:
`npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,router}@latest --save`

Other packages that are installed by the angular cli
`npm install --save core-js@latest rxjs@latest zone.js@latest`

Angular Dev packages:
`npm install --save-dev @angular/{compiler-cli,cli,language-service}@latest`

Types Dev packages:
`npm install --save-dev @types/{jasmine,jasminewd2,node}@latest`

Other packages that are installed as dev dev by the angular cli:
`npm install --save-dev codelyzer@latest jasmine-core@latest jasmine-spec-reporter@latest karma@latest karma-chrome-launcher@latest karma-cli@latest karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@latest karma-jasmine@latest karma-jasmine-html-reporter@latest protractor@latest ts-node@latest tslint@latest`

Install the latest supported version used by the Angular cli (don't do @latest):
`npm install --save-dev typescript@2.4.2`

Rename file angular-cli.json to .angular-cli.json and update the content:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "project3-example"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Note that `rxjs@latest` updated to `6.0.0` which is currenlty not compatible with the last Angular version (`5.2.1`).  I had to revert manually and it was fine.

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE:
Starting from [CLI v6](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4) you can just run [`ng update`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/update) in order to get your dependencies updated automatically to a new version.

> With [`ng update`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/update) sometimes you might want to add `--force` flag.
>   If you do so make sure that the version of typescript you got
>   installed this way is supported by your current angular version,
>   otherwise you might need to downgrade the typescript version.

Also checkout this guide [Updating your Angular projects](https://angular.io/guide/updating)

---

#### *For [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) users only*

If you are on are on `Mac/Linux` or running bash on `Windows`(that wont work in default `Windows CMD`) you can run that oneliner:

`npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,router,compiler-cli}@4.4.5 --save`

`yarn add @angular/{animations,common,compiler,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,router,compiler-cli}@4.4.5`

> Just specify version you wan't e.g @4.4.5 or put @latest to get the latest
>
> Check your `package.json` just to
>   make sure you are updating all `@angular/*` packages that you app is relying on

- To see exact `@angular` version in your project run:
  `npm ls @angular/compiler` or `yarn list @angular/compiler`
- To check the latest stable `@angular` version available on  npm run:
  `npm show @angular/compiler version`

Answer (score 7):

Official npm page suggest a structured method to update angular version for both global and local scenarios.

1.First of all, you need to uninstall the current angular from your
    system.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

2.Clean up the cache

```
npm cache clean
```

***EDIT***

As pointed out by @candidj

`npm cache clean` is renamed as `npm cache verify` from npm 5 onwards

3.Install angular globally

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

4.Local project setup if you have one

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Please check the same down on the link below:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#updating-angular-cli

This will solve the problem.

Comment: `npm cache clean` is now changed to` npm cache verify` as of `npm 5`

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach using [npm-upgrade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade):

1. `npm i -g npm-upgrade`

Go to your project folder

2. `npm-upgrade check`

It will ask you if you wish to upgrade the package, select Yes

That's simple

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install/upgrade all packages to the latest version and you are running windows you can use this in `powershell.exe`:

```
foreach($package in @("animations","common","compiler","core","forms","http","platform-browser","platform-browser-dynamic","router")) {
    npm install @angular/$package@latest -E
}
```

If you also use the `cli`, you can do this:

```
foreach($package in @('animations','common','compiler','core','forms','http','platform-browser','platform-browser-dynamic','router', 'cli','compiler-cli')){
    iex "npm install @angular/$package@latest -E $(If($('cli','compiler-cli').Contains($package)){'-D'})";
}
```

This will save the packages exact (-E), and the cli packages in `devDependencies` (-D)

Comment: it doesn't work for me, always says unmet dependency :/

Comment: @DS_web_developer that's okay. Those are just warnings, not errors

Comment: sadly not, it says FAILED, and my package json is not updated of course (unmet dependencies are for each of the angular packages)

Comment: what are the unmet dependencies?

Comment: well, this is if I do @ next and not latest, just to be clear.... but at least I get the @next version easily so I can update my package.json ;) now all works on ng5.... wooo hooo :)

Comment: Ah, well I guess the unmet dependency is `TypeScript`  then, beacuse the latest ng5 requires a higher ts version :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Just start here:

https://update.angular.io

Select the version you're using and it will give you a step by step guide.

I recommend choosing 'Advanced' to see all steps. Complexity is a relative concept - and I don't know whose stupid idea this feature was, but if you select 'Basic' it won't show you all steps needed and you may miss something important that your otherwise 'Basic' application is using.

[image]

As of version 6 there is a new Angular CLI command `ng update` which intelligently goes through your dependencies and performs checks to make sure you're updating the right things :-)

The steps will outline how to use it :-)

Comment: Don't confuse `NgUpgrade` with `ng update`. `NgUpgrade` is for updating AngularJS to Angular

Comment: Recently I've had many issues updating, especially errors related to angular material. I've had to delete the contents of `node_modules` and run `npm install` the last 3 updates - even 6.0 -> 6.1. No idea why, but if you're getting many odd errors on a simple update then give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

> npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
>
> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
>
> ng update @angular/cli
>
> ng update @angular/core --force
>
> ng update @angular/material or npm i @angular/cdk@6
>   @angular/material@6 --save
>
> npm install typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0'

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking like me for just updating your project to the latest these is what works form me since Angular 6:

> Open the console on your project folder: `If you type: ng update` then you will get the below message:

```
        We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

          Name                               Version                  Command to update
         --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          @angular/cli                       7.0.7 -> 7.2.2           ng update @angular/cli
          @angular/core                      7.0.4 -> 7.2.1           ng update @angular/core

There might be additional packages that are outdated.
    Run "ng update --all" to try to update all at the same time.
```

> So I usually go straight and do:
>
> `ng update --all`
>
> Finally you can check your new version:
>
> ```
> ng version
> ```

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.2
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.2
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.2
@angular/cli                      7.2.2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.2
@schematics/angular               7.2.2
@schematics/update                0.12.2
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.28.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is use the extension(pflannery.vscode-versionlens) in vscode.

this checks for all satisfy and checks for best fit.

i had  lot of issues with updating and keeping my app functioining unitll i let verbose lense did the check and then i run

> npm i

to install newly suggested dependencies.