# Whats the latest version of Angular2 router and how can I update my current older version using a git bash command

Tags: angularjs, git, angular, angular2-routing, git-bash

Whats the latest version of Angular2 router?

and how can I update my current older version using a git bash command?

Comment: This is how you can update your npm dependencies and see their latest version: [How do I correctly upgrade angular 2 (npm) to latest beta?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597780/how-do-i-correctly-upgrade-angular-2-npm-to-latest-beta/36598492#36598492)

Comment: didnt work npm update etc. I just need to update the router so @canActivate works

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the change log for that component in the Angular respository: [Router](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/CHANGELOG.md). The version is listed right at the top.