# How to update angular2 version in meteor project?

Tags: meteor, angular, angular-meteor

I have 2.0.1 version of angular within meteor 1.4 project, how should I upgrade the angular version to the latest 2.1.0? Is changing the version in `package.json` enough?

```
   "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
        "@angular/forms": "2.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.1",
        "@angular/router": "3.0.1",
        "angular2-file-drop": "0.0.5",
        "angular2-google-maps": "0.15.0",
        "angular2-meteor": "0.7.0",
        "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "0.8.0",
        "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "^0.1.1",
        "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "0.0.2",
        "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
        "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.3",
        "meteor-rxjs": "0.3.0",
        "ng2-pagination": "0.4.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "zone.js": "0.6.21"
      },
```

Comment: It may be enough, but you should re-run all of your tests afterwards to make sure that everything still works.

Comment: It is not different in Meteor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597780/how-do-i-correctly-upgrade-angular-2-npm-to-the-latest-version