# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I get this below error after upgrading my angular-cli

```
ERROR in Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'index' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. ("own)="handleKeydown($event, item)"
             (onTagEdited)="onTagEdited.emit(item)"
             [ERROR ->][index]="i"
             [attr.tabindex]="readonly ? -1 : 0"
             [class.readonly]="readonly""): TagInputComponent@16:13

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\xxxx\yyyy\eeeee\eeee\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 5:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

This error happens when i run `ng build --prod` and works fine when i run `ng build` without any parameters,

Comment: update `angular-cli` to the last version, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Answer (score 41):

When you run the ng build in angular 2, latest angular-cli automatically runs with --aot parameter (ahead of time compilation), so it is trying to optimize your code. You are having a package that is not yet compatible for optimizing. So you need update to your packages. Most probably the packages that has `**forRoot()**` in your app.module.ts

**I recommend to update all packages.**

Easy way to update your package is to use ncu npm package as in below, which i got it from [How do I correctly upgrade angular 2 (npm) to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597780/how-do-i-correctly-upgrade-angular-2-npm-to-the-latest-version)

Install

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Usage

`ncu` for display

`ncu -u` for re-writing your package.json

and run `npm install` to update your packages

If above did not work, you might need to update your code for aot compliance. Refer this url below to make changes in your code.
 https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/getting-your-angular-2-library-ready-for-aot-90d1347bcad

Comment: Sounded good but unfortunately you get that same error from angular-cli building a brand new application generated with ng new.  No changes are required, just build with --prod and it fails.

Comment: Did you try updating the package using ncu?

Comment: Worked for me Thanks :)

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue and how I ended up resolving it was:
Delete the enhanced-resolve module from node_modules and then run

```
npm install enhanced-resolve@3.3.0
```

After that aot builds worked as expected...

Comment: Wow funny but it worked ... I add it to my package.json with v 3.3.0 to fix the build server too

Answer (score 28):

Use:

```
ng build --env=prod
```

instead of:

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: This will not build optimized distribution package, for more information refer to angular cli documentation here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Answer (score 13):

Faced second part of this issue.

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'
```

Resolved it by updating angular/cli to 1.2.6 for angular 4

1. Remove node_modules folder
2. Update "@angular/cli": "1.0.4" to "@angular/cli": "1.2.6" in package.json under devDependencies
3. Run npm install

Then executing "ng build --prod" successfully generated the production build.

Comment: build successfully, But errors are there after running `index.html` directly, any idea ?

Comment: while running `index.html` got this error in developer console `SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL .....cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL `

Comment: Worked for me! Might want to also remove your package-lock.json in addition to node modules folder.

Answer (score 2):

Same error after upgrading from Angular 6 to 7.1.4. I followed the instructions found [here](https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/upgrade-to-angular-7-beta-within-10-minutes-c14fc380edd).

The error returned was:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.server.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
```

When trying to pre-render using the command.

```
ng run [my-project-name]:server
```

The reason was I enabled the Ivy Render which is not production [ready](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706).
By removing the lines:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true
}
```

From the tsconfig.json file, all was well in the world again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this unhelpful and confusing error message can be caused by using default exports in your typescript consumed by Angular AOT (prerendering).  Using `export default class` will cause this error with any version of Angular and is currently unsupported.  You must change to `export class`.

To view the current status of the issue and see if it ever gets fixed, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11402.  As of my writing this, the issue has been open for over two years, but they do claim it will get fixed one day.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I haven't declared my newly created component in module.ts. It worked when I declared it. Check if any of your components are not declared in module.ts.