# How to upgrade from Angular 4.2.4 to Angular 4.3

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

I'm using angular 4.2.4 in my application and I want to upgrade to the latest one (4.3.0)

is there an easy and safe way to do that without breaking my application ?

When searching I found this information from:

http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2017/07/angular-43-now-available.html

that link states that Angular 4.3 contains no breaking changes ?

I want to do that upgrade to use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be fine. Once you reference the new packages just make sure that your `ng build --prod` is not breaking.

If you want to use the new `HttpClient` you have change all parts of your code that referencing `Http` from `@angular/http` and replace that with `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` according with styleguide.

Also you have to change to all related `.spec` files that referencing old `Http` as well, then test with `ng t`, unless you does not care about tests.

If you are looking how upgrade all angular related packages more efficiently just look here [How do I correctly upgrade angular 2 (npm) to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36597780/415078)

Comment: Does `@angular/common/http` have backward compatibility? Can I use `Http` from `@angular/http` after updating my package from `@angular/common: 4.0.2` to `@angular/common: 4.3.0`?

Comment: @JosephKatzman checkout this article https://medium.com/@amcdnl/the-new-http-client-in-angular-4-3-754bd3ff83a8 you have to adjust your code a bit as a new `http client` resolving your json now, so you do not have to do things like `result.json`, etc

Comment: Thanks for the article. I read it. Looks like there is no way to use `Http` from `@angular/http` after upgrading to `@angular/common: 4.3.0`.

Comment: @JosephKatzman It is depends what version of angular you are upgrading to. It is definitely not available in the latest. They deprecate the old `http` but kept until version 5 as far for my memory. Then they didn't ship that with the latest angular versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NPM command to update the installed all dependencies.

To update angular

```
npm install angular@version  (Provide version number) 

Example : npm install angular@4.3
```

To download latest angular you can use `npm install angular@latest`

The command `npm update -D` && `npm update -S will` update all packages inside package.json to their latest version.

You can also apply the same command to update HttpClient as wells as all other dependencies

For my application I have upgraded from 4.2.4 to 4.3. Everything works fine. No more issues