# Upgrading Angular 5.2.7 to 5.2.10

Tags: angular, upgrade

I have created an Angular project using older cli version which by default installed Angular version 5.2.7 but now I want to upgrade my application to latest stable angular build i.e. 5.2.10.

So the problem which I am struggling is that when we install angular package we have also installed other packages such as animation, http, forms, core, common and etc. And all these modules are dependent. If there is any version mismatch then application will break.

So the question is, what are those packages which need to be updated when we want to upgrade our angular version?
Where we can find list of all the package dependencies(with their compatible version no) that need to be upgraded along with a new angular version.

Does official angular development team or may be their git hub page contains these dependencies list?

Comment: same way as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597780/how-do-i-correctly-upgrade-angular-2-npm-to-the-latest-version should work..

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909868/how-to-upgrade-from-angular-4-2-4-to-angular-4-3

Comment: For updating manually also you need to know which package and what version... thats what I am asking. Because all the dependencies dont have same version no as of angular..

Answer (score 0):

This could be of some help.
This provides list of changes we need in order to upgrade form one version to another.

https://update.angular.io/

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Open your package.json and find "5.2.7" and replace with "5.2.10" than remove your node_modules folder and run,

```
npm install
```

I hope, it should work.