# Error updating Angular using npm

Tags: angular, npm

I am really at a loss here. I have installed ngx-translate for my application, but it requires me to update my @angular/core and rxjs. I decided to update Angular completely, using https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/. It told me to:

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.0.0' @angular/common@'^5.0.0'
@angular/compiler@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.0.0' @angular/core@'^5.0.0' 
@angular/forms@'^5.0.0' @angular/http@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.0.0' 
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.0.0' 
@angular/platform-server@'^5.0.0' @angular/router@'^5.0.0'typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
```

When I paste this into my console and hit enter, I get the following errors:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@angular/animations@'5.0.0'" "@angular/common@'5.0.0'" "@angular/compiler@'5.0.0'" "@angular/compiler-cli@'5.0.0'" "@angular/core@'5.0.0'" "@angular/forms@'5.0.0'" "@angular/http@'5.0.0'" "@angular/platform-browser@'5.0.0'" "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'5.0.0'" "@angular/platform-server@'5.0.0'" "@angular/router@'5.0.0'" "typescript@2.4.2" "rxjs@'5.5.2'"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: rxjs@'5.5.2'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 6.0.0-alpha.0, 5.5.6, 5.5.5, 5.5.4, 5.5.3, 5.5.2, 5.5.1, 5.5.0, 5.5.0-beta.7, 5.5.0-beta.5, 5.5.0-beta.4, 5.5.0-beta.3, 5.5.0-beta.2, 5.5.0-beta.1, 5.5.0-beta.0, 5.4.3, 5.4.2, 5.4.1, 5.4.0, 5.3.3, 5.3.1, 5.3.0, 5.2.1-smooth, 5.2.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.0, 5.0.3, 5.0.2, 5.0.1, 5.0.0, 5.0.0-rc.5, 5.0.0-rc.4, 5.0.0-rc.3, 5.0.0-rc.2, 5.0.0-rc.1, 5.0.0-beta.12, 5.0.0-beta.11, 5.0.0-beta.10, 5.0.0-beta.9, 5.0.0-beta.8, 5.0.0-beta.7, 5.0.0-beta.6, 5.0.0-beta.5, 5.0.0-beta.4, 5.0.0-beta.3, 5.0.0-beta.2, 5.0.0-beta.1, 5.0.0-beta.0, 5.0.0-alpha.14, 5.0.0-alpha.13, 5.0.0-alpha.12, 5.0.0-alpha.11, 5.0.0-alpha.10
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\pdws-view-v2\npm-debug.log
```

I have also tried to to only update @angular/core and rxjs, but when I for example `npm install @angular/core@5.0.0` I get these message:

```
+-- @angular/cli@1.2.0
| `-- rxjs@5.5.6
|   `-- symbol-observable@1.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.0.0
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY  (rxjs) invalid error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\pdws-view-v2\node_modules\rxjs\package.json
```

And a bunch of warnings like this one:

```
npm WARN @angular/animations@4.4.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.4 but none was installed.
```

Also, after attempting to install these, my application won't compile anymore, giving me this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\pdws-view-v2\node_modules\@angular\core\@angular\core.es5.js'
    at Error (native)
 @ ./src/main.ts 1:0-47
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

What do I do at this point? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the cache and reinstalled

```
npm cache clean
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.0.0' @angular/common@'^5.0.0'
@angular/compiler@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.0.0' @angular/core@'^5.0.0' 
@angular/forms@'^5.0.0' @angular/http@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.0.0' 
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.0.0' 
@angular/platform-server@'^5.0.0' @angular/router@'^5.0.0'typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
```

Comment: Any reason why you only mentioned @angular/animations and @angular/common?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add others :)

Comment: I'm getting the same error :/ It didn't change anything

Comment: hope this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597780/how-do-i-correctly-upgrade-angular-2-npm-to-the-latest-version

Comment: Haven't been able to fix it. I'm also getting this error:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted`

I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162046/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-jesper).